Convert extended Ascii (>127) to standard Ascii (<128) in Java
We receive UTF-8 compliant data from a 3rd party system. Our system can handle it since it is also UTF-8 compliant. The problem is that old downstream systems can not always handle characters with a decimal value > 127 and either break or display the data incorrectly.
Since we do not have control over the downstream systems, the only way to fix this issue is to convert the "extended" Ascii characters to their "base" (Ascii < 128) values e.g. ê, ë must become e, or ò, ö must become o, etc.
Is there a way to achieve this in Java without having to hard code the mappings?

What about Japanese, Chinese, Korean, Arabic...?

German has ways to avoid their special characters in computer systems. "ä"->"ae", "ß"->"ss", you get the idea. I bet other european languages have similar rules.

What languages do you need to support "properly"? As paddy noted, there won't be a general utf-8 to ascii conversion, many utf-8-characters will have to be encoded as something human-unreadable

and do you ever need to convert back from ascii to utf-8? That also constrains the solution

hardcode mapping is probably inevitable if you want a kind of meaningful conversion.

We are in an English speaking country with strong German and Dutch influence. We don't have to cater for Japanese, Chinese, Korean, etc. 99% of the time we get ë or  é or ö, but it will be nice to cater for all vowels that have variations.

you can use java.text.Normalizer for most of these characters, but it will not handle all (e.g. the German ß) || BTW the information from previous comment should be included into the question, please [edit]

Will your English-writing users won't ever use emoji? If they do, what behavior do you want?

(sorry, that "won't" in the middle was a typo. O meant to just ask, "will your English-writing users ever use emoji")

You can 'normalize' utf-8, which seperates diacritical marks and vowels (the string will look the same) then strip the diacritical marks. These actions effectively turns "é" into "e" (but also "ä" into "a")1
Afterwards, escape all other characters that may be in your input to their hex-codes using UnicodeEscaper from apache-commons. This won't be human-readable, but it will protect your legacy systems from special characters.
@Test
void test() {
    String input = "äéöíæ";
    String normalized = asciify(input);
    System.out.println("Original: " + input);
    System.out.println("Normalized: " + normalized);
}

public static String asciify(String input) {
    String s = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
    UnicodeEscaper escaper = UnicodeEscaper.above(127);
    return escaper.translate(s);
}

prints:
Original: äéöíæ
Normalized: aeoi\u00E6

1 if you want to support conversions like "ä"->"ae", hardcode them and replace them before this step, but you indicated in your comments that you do not need German and a quick google-search told me that German is actually an outlier with these two-character conversions. 

be aware that the Normalizer does NOT normalize the German ß, as I already commented  - this must be done separately (e.g. replace('ß', 's'))

@user85421 the correct German replacement would be 'ss'. But yes, you are right.

I know that the korrekt replacement would be ss, but in question OP wrote:  "ö must become o" (not oe) so I suppose they only want/need the first letter

@user85421 I understood that to mean that they do not care about German text, but I realize now this interpretation is false as they specifically mention German as one of their input-languages. Maybe OP simply does not know "oe" is the conventional replacement for "ö" in German and is wrongly designing the requirements?

or maybe the overall length of the data should not be changed (must be constant length) - we do not know, I just wanted to add the note so they are aware that ß is not converted in at all

You can use a Transliterator from ICU4J.
Assuming the input only contains Latin letters, the Latin-ASCII transliterator can remove diacritics from Latin letters.
System.out.println(Transliterator.getInstance("Latin-ASCII").transliterate("òóâì"));
// prints ooai

You might also want to replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}", "") just to be safe.
If you know more about the input, like what language it is written in, you can use a transliterator specifically for that language. For example, if you know the text is in German, you can use de-ASCII instead. This will use transformation rules specific to German, like replacing "ö" with "oe".
For other transliterators you can use, see the ICU documentation.

Better than my answer, but I'll leave mine up for people who don't want the dependency.
